# A embedding of tensor product over semisimple algebras

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, tensor-products

Let $R$ be a semisimple Artinian algebra over the complex number field $\mathbb{C}$, that is, $R$ is isomorphic a finite direct product of matrix rings over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $S$ be a ideal of $R$, and so we can view $S$ as a direct summand of $R$, and so it is isomorphic to a finite product of matrix rings as well. Now let $V$ and $W$ be $R$-modules. In addition, let $V' \subseteq V$ , $W' \subseteq W$ be $S$-submodules, respectively.

$\textbf{My question}$: How can we prove that there is an natural embedding(i.e., a injective linear map) from  $V'\otimes_S W'$ to $V\otimes_R W$? I hope it is $v'\otimes_S w' \mapsto v'\otimes_R w'$, for all $v'\in V', w'\in W'$. Thanks very much!

Comment: from the universal property of tensor products it is straightforward i guess. try it.